# Elasticsearch match certain fields exactly but not others

Tags: elasticsearch

I am needing ElasticSearch to match certain fields exactly, currently using multi_match.

For example, a user types in `long beach chiropractor`.

I want `long beach` to match the city field exactly, and not return results for `seal beach` or `glass beach`.

At the same time `chiropractor` should also match `chiropractic`.

Here is the current query I am using:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
            {
                "multi_match": {
                                "fields": [
                                    "title",
                                    "location_address_address_1.value",
                                    "location_address_city.value^2",
                                    "location_address_state.value",
                                    "specialty" // e.g. chiropractor
                                ],
                                "query": "chiropractor long beach",
                                "boost": 6,
                                "type": "cross_fields"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

The right approach would be to separate term that is searched and location, and store location as keyword type. If that's not possible then you can use synonym tokenizer to store locations as single tokens, but this will require to have the list of all possible locations. e.g.

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "my_synonym_filter": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms": [
            "long beach=>long-beach"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_synonyms": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_synonym_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now if you call

```
POST /my_index/_analyze?analyzer=my_synonyms    
{
    "text": ["chiropractor long beach"]
}
```

the response is

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "chiropractor",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 12,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "long-beach",
            "start_offset": 13,
            "end_offset": 23,
            "type": "SYNONYM",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```